# How to serialize javascript function from .NET string

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

MVC4 Razor view shound contain function definition returned from viewmodel:

```
<script>
var colmodel = { onClick: function() { 
                   alert('Click'); 
                   }
               };
</script>
```

I tried to use

```
var colmodel=@Html.Raw(Model.Definition());
```

And in viewmodel

```
public string Definition() {
  return Json.Encode( new { onClick= @"function() { 
                   alert('Click'); 
                   }
" );
 }
```

but it returns string property instead of javascript function object.
How to fix this so that javascript function definition appears in view ?

ASP.NET MVC4, C#, Razor, Jquery are used.

Comment: The code in your view model will not even compile

Comment: You can't pass a function object in JSON, and in MVC your ViewModel shouldn't be handling view matters like JS.

Comment: Same view is used to edit multiple tables. Different table require different javascript functions for properties. How to pass them to view if viewmodel cannot used ? Current function definitions are placed  between $$ characters and those are removed from json string before passing to view. I asked for more native way.

Comment: What you are trying to do should work, a string is what you want. Everything you build in a razor template is a string which is interpreted by the engine before generating the response. But it is hard to give advice when what you have shown would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a string returning function:

```
public string Definition() {
  return "{ onClick: function() { alert('Click'); }};";
}
```

And the semicolon is not necessary at the end of:

`var colmodel=@Html.Raw(Model.Definition())`